# All components id changed to random number

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, android-resources

I lost my project folder so I decode the APK using `ApkTool` and `java2dex`. now all my java classes that contain so many components has changed its id to a random number.

something like this:

```
this.time = (EditText)findviewById(2131296533);
```

it should be “time” instead of the number. and it’s affected to about a hundred of them.

I’ve tried using another reverse engineering APK on the website but the result is the same.

I also noticed some codes also changed. I hope you guys could help me out. this is my final year project!! thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because R.id.* are constants generated by your IDE, which are discarded at compile time. It is possible to get your names from Id's

> in `res/values`, you can find the id using name in public.xml (or something similar, e.g. publics.xml or name.xml). That's it.

src https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12733/mapping-android-resource-ids-to-resource-string

Comment: I see the relation between the number and the Id's but now i need to convert the 
 hex to decimal for each component. is there any quick ways? sorry for asking!

Comment: I don't know any quick method, except writing some code that does it for you

Comment: I don't think it has. Why don't you create new IDs?